# Universal directory format for both windows or unix

Tags: coldfusion

I am working on a side project that is meant to be deployable on CF servers residing on both windows and unix systems. Is there a way that I can manage absolute pathing in directory structures in a way that would be universal? In other words, I don't want have to have a bunch of conditional statements littering the code to manage if you are windows versus unix servers.

I've been working exclusively in unix-based OS for the past 8 years, so it's been a long time since I had to worry about Windows.

I am working in CF 9.01 FWIW.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a specific problem, or are you imagining one?

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [ColdFusion System Functions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec1a60c-7ffc.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-69b7).  You can use some of those functions to dynamically retrieve pathing information from the server, regardless of the platform.

Just create a test.cfm file and start outputting those values to get familiar with them.  I think these will be of particular interest.

Sample test.cfm:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
<body>
    <cfoutput>
        <p>GetBaseTemplatePath() = #GetBaseTemplatePath()#</p>
        <p>GetDirectoryFromPath(GetBaseTemplatePath()) = #GetDirectoryFromPath(GetBaseTemplatePath())#</p>
        <p>GetCurrentTemplatePath() = #GetCurrentTemplatePath()#</p>
        <p>ExpandPath("*.*") = #ExpandPath("*.*")#</p>
    </cfoutput>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And remember to always use front slashes when building paths. They will work on all platforms.